# Failed to connect to sql data base on remote pc on network

Tags: sql-server-2005, connection-string, database-connection

I had windows application installed on pc on network and connect to sql database on other pc I had my connection string well but error apeared that I cannot connect to database

Comment: What's the error message? Is Windows firewall blocking the connection?

Comment: an error occured while establishing a connection to the server when connecting to sql server 2005, 
this failure may be caused by the fact that under the defult
 setting sql server dosenot allow remote connection .(provider:tcp provider ,eror:0 neo connection could be .....

Comment: have you checked that the SQL Server you are using, allows remote connection??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the guys have already said, this is highly likely to be a firewall or other networking issue, but if you have checked that all through then the following might help.

1) Open up SQL Server Configuration Manager
2) Look in the tree on the left and expand SQL Server Network Configuration
3) Highlight the SQL Server you are looking for (I have SQL Express And SQL Server)
4) On the Right Hand side you will see a list of installed protocols and whether or not they are enabled.

From there enable the protocol you are looking to use.